# ATMEGA328p powersupply 3.8volt and Sensor 5V input power

Tags: arduino, voltage, sensor

I have a little doubt.
If I use a microcontroller powered by 3.7volt from a lithium battery and I want to connect a sensor that needs 5 volts of power(external).

Can works the ADC of microcontroller 3.7V PSupply to receive 5 volt signals from the sensor at the same time to make the equation conversion then correctly?

[The answer is NO]

***Datasheet***

[ATMEGA328p AU](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061A.pdf)

[ANALOG WATER PRESSURE SENSOR](https://www.iot-store.com.au/products/dfrobot-gravity-analog-water-pressure-sensor)

Comment: Please provide links to the **manufacturer's** datasheets for the microcontroller and sensor...they are not all the same.

Comment: Possibly, though you will need to convert the sensor output as well.  Designing battery powered systems that work well is *hard*.  Also pay attention to the true voltage range of your battery, which is not meaningfully described by "3.7volt"

Comment: @ElliotAlderson added

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am using this https://core-electronics.com.au/polymer-lithium-ion-battery-6000mah.html  But the 3.7 volts is a reference, maybe I would consider a range between 3.3 volt and 3.7 volt

Comment: Sounds like you need to spend quite a bit more time learning about lithium batteries before you consider using one, as your current idea of the range is extremely incorrect.  Really it would be best if you used alkaline cells until you have substantially more experience.  Also note that the quiescent current of your sensor will quickly drain your battery; you'll need to not only sleep the MCU but power down the sensor between intermittent wakeups to poll.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to step down analog sensor signal voltage using voltage divider](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/276337/how-to-step-down-analog-sensor-signal-voltage-using-voltage-divider)

Comment: @ChrisStratton I dont need sleep mode in MCU I am using a timer TPL5110

Comment: @ElliotAlderson is not duplicate, similar maybe

Comment: It's is in fact a duplicate of the *answerable* part of your question.  The *unanswerable* and *too broad* parts about the power sources don't count.

Comment: mmm... The solution so is a step-up convert to get 5V in the system. I thought you could answer me if I could read 5V data in the MCU ADC running at 3.7volt

Comment: First, answers go in the answer field, not as edits to the question.  But no, the answer is not "no" in other than the most bull-headed and counterproductively unimaginative sense - see the linked duplicate to see how the answer can practically be made "yes".  Or if you're going to stick with your plan to use a boost converter for the sensor and run the whole thing off a dedicated power timer rather than sleep the MCU, you could run the MCU off the boost too.  Do beware boost supplies are often noisy.

Comment: Okay I understand. but the problem is not the resistor for voltage divider, the problem is I dont have 5V for the Sensor 5VDC...Maybe the sensor works with 3.7volts but I will need recalcute the equation of unit conversion simply :S

Comment: You've already proposed a boost converter.  That may bring added challenges, but it can be done.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I will use a boost

Answer (score 0):

"could read 5V data in the MCU ADC running at 3.7volt"

With a '328P, the sensed voltage cannot exceed the supply voltage by more than 0.5V. The input protection diodes clamp the level to no more than that.  If the voltage is higher and enough current flows (generally more than 1mA), the diode will often fail (shorted) and introduce 5V into the Vcc line in the 328P die and possibly cause the whole chip to fail. (Altho in this case, perhaps not as the chip typically runs at 5V). The ADC would likely just return 1023 as a reading.

Personally, I would use a boost converter from Pololu.com to boost the 3.7-4.2V output from the Li battery to a steady 5V and run from that.  Example:

https://www.pololu.com/product/2115

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I don't use the output voltage 5V or apply load to this, will it drain my battery ??

Comment: Yes: 2 mA typical no-load quiescent current.

Comment: @asterix You'd either want a boost converter with an enable, or to power it from your proposed time sequence power switch chip.

Comment: The truth is that it is not possible to do that, because it is a project for IoT where to save energy the PCB power system is controlled under a tpl5510 timer, so there are no alternatives to control the boost using an ON / OFF pin From the MCU, the boost must continuously supply power to the timer and the rest of the circuit.
I wanted to avoid the use of boost converter because I did not want unnecessary power consumption while the circuit remains off. I don't like that the sensors work with 5V.

Comment: Use Resistor-divider to scale down to 1.1V max and use the internal band-gap reference then, that will overcome any Vcc variation as the battery drops from 4.1 or 4.2V fully charged down to 3.7V or lower.